# Why can't I open Tk in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6, tk-toolkit

I coded this game myself. It is a guessing game regarding 2 players.

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

p1 = 0 
p2 = 0
while p1 < 3 and p2 < 3:
 answer = randint(0,16)
 wrong_answer = randint(0,16)
 wrong_answer1 = randint(0,16)


 s_list =    ["apple","book","phone","sheep","ruler","pen","eraser","knife","cement","Google","file","stapler","thermometer","box","glue","yes","no"]
 hint_list = ["Fruit","Read","Technology","Animal","Measure Length","Writing","Stationary","Cut  food", "Building Material","Search Engine","Paper organizer","Binding papers together","Temperature","Storage","Attach things together","Approval","Disapproval"]
 secret_word = s_list[answer]
 hint = f'Hint:{hint_list[answer]}'
 incorrect = s_list[answer]
 incorrect1 = s_list[answer]


 master = Tk()
 master.title("2 Players Guessing Game!")
 master.geometry('700x900+90+90')

 def random1():
   global p1
   p1 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Correct! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random2():
   global p2
   p2 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Incorrect! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random3():
   global p2
   p2 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Correct! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random4():
   global p1
   p1 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Incorrect! Score:",p1 ,p2

 label = Label(master, text="2 Player Guessing Game!", font  = "Arial 14")
 label2 = Label(master, text="<- P1", font = "Arial 14")
 label3 = Label(master, text="P2 ->", font = "Arial 14")
 button = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random1)
 button2 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
 button3 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
 button4 = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random3)
 button5 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
 button6 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
 label4 = Label(master, text=hint, font = "Arial 14")


 label.pack()
 label2.pack()
 label3.pack()
 label4.pack()
 button.pack(side=LEFT)
 button2.pack(side=LEFT)
 button3.pack(side=LEFT)
 button4.pack(side=RIGHT)
 button5.pack(side=RIGHT)
 button6.pack(side=RIGHT)



 if p1 == 3:
   label["text"] = "Player 1 won!"
   exit()
 elif p2 == 3:
   label["text"] = "Player 2 won!"
   exit()
 else:
   continue
```

Before I added this "continue" , I could print Tk properly but could not loop. After adding "continue", my Tk can't even load now. Why? Please help. Thanks.

```
mainloop()
```

The reason why I did not use PyGame is because I wanted my game to be a "Answer first, get point" type of game.

Comment: It is because `continue` will skip the code followed and start from the beginning of `while` loop.  That means `mainloop()` will be skipped when the first two if conditions return False.

Comment: that means my mainloop() should be above continue?

Comment: Check what I have put that should work for you

Comment: Actually you should not put that if block there because it is useless.  You should note that `tkinter` is event-driven.

Comment: Currently, the question and the options are all the same. Like this my game is no fun as the players will know the answers once they click the correct one. As such, I need to edit my code such that the question and the options change. But I do not know how to do it. Can someone help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `master.mainloop()` at the end and getting rid of continue

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

p1 = 0
p2 = 0
while p1 < 3 and p2 < 3:
 answer = randint(0,16)
 wrong_answer = randint(0,16)
 wrong_answer1 = randint(0,16)


 s_list =    ["apple","book","phone","sheep","ruler","pen","eraser","knife","cement","Google","file","stapler","thermometer","box","glue","yes","no"]
 hint_list = ["Fruit","Read","Technology","Animal","Measure Length","Writing","Stationary","Cut  food", "Building Material","Search Engine","Paper organizer","Binding papers together","Temperature","Storage","Attach things together","Approval","Disapproval"]
 secret_word = s_list[answer]
 hint = f'Hint:{hint_list[answer]}'
 incorrect = s_list[answer]
 incorrect1 = s_list[answer]


 master = Tk()
 master.title("2 Players Guessing Game!")
 master.geometry('700x900+90+90')

 def random1():
   global p1
   p1 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Correct! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random2():
   global p2
   p2 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Incorrect! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random3():
   global p2
   p2 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Correct! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random4():
   global p1
   p1 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Incorrect! Score:",p1 ,p2

 label = Label(master, text="2 Player Guessing Game!", font  = "Arial 14")
 label2 = Label(master, text="<- P1", font = "Arial 14")
 label3 = Label(master, text="P2 ->", font = "Arial 14")
 button = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random1)
 button2 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
 button3 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
 button4 = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random3)
 button5 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
 button6 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
 label4 = Label(master, text=hint, font = "Arial 14")


 label.pack()
 label2.pack()
 label3.pack()
 label4.pack()
 button.pack(side=LEFT)
 button2.pack(side=LEFT)
 button3.pack(side=LEFT)
 button4.pack(side=RIGHT)
 button5.pack(side=RIGHT)
 button6.pack(side=RIGHT)

 if p1 == 3:
   label["text"] = "Player 1 won!"
   exit()
 elif p2 == 3:
   label["text"] = "Player 2 won!"
   exit()

 master.mainloop()
```

This works for me.

Comment: how about if both players score is less than 3?

Comment: do if p1 < 3 and p2 < 3:

Answer (score 1):

You need to call mainloop() at some point to get the window to show, your cord should look something like this:

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

p1 = 0 
p2 = 0
while p1 < 3 and p2 < 3:
 answer = randint(0,16)
 wrong_answer = randint(0,16)
 wrong_answer1 = randint(0,16)


 s_list =    ["apple","book","phone","sheep","ruler","pen","eraser","knife","cement","Google","file","stapler","thermometer","box","glue","yes","no"]
 hint_list = ["Fruit","Read","Technology","Animal","Measure Length","Writing","Stationary","Cut  food", "Building Material","Search Engine","Paper organizer","Binding papers together","Temperature","Storage","Attach things together","Approval","Disapproval"]
 secret_word = s_list[answer]
 hint = f'Hint:{hint_list[answer]}'
 incorrect = s_list[answer]
 incorrect1 = s_list[answer]


 master = Tk()
 master.title("2 Players Guessing Game!")
 master.geometry('700x900+90+90')

 def random1():
   global p1
   p1 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Correct! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random2():
   global p2
   p2 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Incorrect! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random3():
   global p2
   p2 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Correct! Score:",p1 ,p2

 def random4():
   global p1
   p1 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Incorrect! Score:",p1 ,p2

 label = Label(master, text="2 Player Guessing Game!", font  = "Arial 14")
 label2 = Label(master, text="<- P1", font = "Arial 14")
 label3 = Label(master, text="P2 ->", font = "Arial 14")
 button = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random1)
 button2 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
 button3 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
 button4 = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random3)
 button5 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
 button6 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
 label4 = Label(master, text=hint, font = "Arial 14")


 label.pack()
 label2.pack()
 label3.pack()
 label4.pack()
 button.pack(side=LEFT)
 button2.pack(side=LEFT)
 button3.pack(side=LEFT)
 button4.pack(side=RIGHT)
 button5.pack(side=RIGHT)
 button6.pack(side=RIGHT)

 master.mainloop()
```

[Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)
I hope this helps

Comment: But I want to include " Player 1 won" or "Player 2 part"

Comment: Then you can place it respectivly to where you want it put

Answer (score 0):

GUI toolkits like `tkinter` are *event-driven*. To work properly, the `mainloop` must continuously be able to process keyboard and mouse events.

So they work quite differently from normal Python scripts that just run from top to bottom.

A `tkinter` program *runs within the `mainloop`*.
So there are only three things you do before starting the `mainloop`.

- Create a window with some widgets on it.
- Initialize global program state.
- Define functions that can be run from the `mainloop` as *callbacks* or *idle tasks*.

A callback is called in response to activating a control (like clicking on a button).

An idle task is started by the system after a specified number of milliseconds when the system is not busy processing events. You can schedule idle tasks with the `Tk.after()` method.

Basically, the callbacks and idle tasks *are* your program.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that `tkinter` is event-driven, and you should not apply procedural/sequential programming on it.

For your case, you don't need the `while` loop and you should put the checking winner logic in a function and call it inside those `randomX()` functions:

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

p1 = 0 
p2 = 0

answer = randint(0,16)
wrong_answer = randint(0,16)
wrong_answer1 = randint(0,16)

s_list =    ["apple","book","phone","sheep","ruler","pen","eraser","knife","cement","Google","file","stapler","thermometer","box","glue","yes","no"]
hint_list = ["Fruit","Read","Technology","Animal","Measure Length","Writing","Stationary","Cut  food", "Building Material","Search Engine","Paper organizer","Binding papers together","Temperature","Storage","Attach things together","Approval","Disapproval"]
secret_word = s_list[answer]
hint = f'Hint:{hint_list[answer]}'
incorrect = s_list[answer]
incorrect1 = s_list[answer]

master = Tk()
master.title("2 Players Guessing Game!")
master.geometry('700x900+90+90')

def check_winner():
    winner = 1 if p1 == 3 else 2 if p2 == 3 else None
    if winner:
        print(f'Player {winner} won!')
        master.destroy() # end the program

def random1():
   global p1
   p1 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Correct! Score:",p1 ,p2
   check_winner()

def random2():
   global p2
   p2 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Incorrect! Score:",p1 ,p2
   check_winner()

def random3():
   global p2
   p2 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Correct! Score:",p1 ,p2
   check_winner()

def random4():
   global p1
   p1 += 1
   label4["text"] = "Incorrect! Score:",p1 ,p2
   check_winner()

label = Label(master, text="2 Player Guessing Game!", font  = "Arial 14")
label2 = Label(master, text="<- P1", font = "Arial 14")
label3 = Label(master, text="P2 ->", font = "Arial 14")
button = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random1)
button2 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
button3 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random2)
button4 = Button(master, text=secret_word, font = "Arial 14", command=random3)
button5 = Button(master, text=incorrect, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
button6 = Button(master, text=incorrect1, font = "Arial 14", command=random4)
label4 = Label(master, text=hint, font = "Arial 14")

label.pack()
label2.pack()
label3.pack()
label4.pack()
button.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4.pack(side=RIGHT)
button5.pack(side=RIGHT)
button6.pack(side=RIGHT)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: umm how do i like refresh the question and its options?

Comment: Because if it is the same question and options, the game will not be fun anymore

Comment: Actually I don't really get your game logic.  How your game behave is another question.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: can i use master.exit() ??

Comment: What I mean is that I don't understand your game logic/flow.  If you want to change your game logic, raise another SO question.